# FTDI2232d + TM4C1294 configurations

Tags: microcontroller, usb, uart, jtag, ftdi

I posted this question before, but I am still struggling with this.
I captured a schematic and others in this time so it should be more clear to see what's going on.

I was given a custom board including Tiva C TM4C1294 + other components on it. Unlike EK-TM4C, FTDI2232d is applied on the custom board.

**I have tried to configure ft2232 using FT Prog and programmed .bin into the custom board, but nothing works so far.**

Here is a schematic for FT2232D interfacing TM4C:
[image]

Here is My Computer's hardware Configurations:

[image]

Here is how I set up using FT Prog:

[image]

I have chose other options but nothing works. According to the schematic Ch A is MPSSE mode
[image]

Also I have tried on different options, but...
[image]

For the Ch B, 232 UART and Virtual Com Port are selected.

[image]

As I program .bin into the custom board. It says "**unable to find a target**"
I am not sure what is wrong with it.

Thanks,
Jin

Comment: Get a LM3S9B96 development board. Use FT Prog to read out its configuration. Write this configuration into your custom board.

Comment: I haven't used that FTProg before, but is it configured to connect to either your COM28 or COM29? It looks like that is where your FTDI is connected (assuming it is connected in that screenshot)

Comment: In LMFlash, sometimes it can help to reduce the JTAG clock speed. Try going down to 500k or 250k just to rule out noise issues. Also, you don't know whether the FT2232 is using VCP driver or D2XX driver. Finally, ask TI for help; they would know the answer.

Comment: every times my computer reboots, it detects VID in FTDI chip as a new and increases the port numbers. Since I chose both Ch A and B for VCP, that's why two com ports are shown up.

Comment: I read LM3S9b96 config thru Ft prog and applied it into the tm4c custom board, but it's still same.Ch A is set as 245 Fifo /d2xx direct and Ch B 232 uart/vcp. One thing different is custom board is sourced from external 5v power supply and LM3S uses bus power.